# Como crio um banco de dados no HSQLDB?

Tags: banco-de-dados, hsqldb

Geralmente para criar um banco de dados é através do comando `CREATE database` e o nome do banco.

Porém, eu preciso ajudar um amigo meu para um trabalho de faculdade, e não consigo descobrir como cria um *database* neste banco de dados.

Quero criar um novo *database* para fazer a conexão no Eclipse. Como se cria um banco de dados com o HSQLDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo a [**documentação**](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/running-chapt.html#rgc_new_db):

> When a server instance is started, or when a connection is made to an in-process database, a new, empty database is created if no database exists at the given path.

Ou seja, não há um `create database ...` para se criar um banco de dados, basta instanciar uma conexão:

```
Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:/opt/db/testdb", "SA", "");
```

O método acima cria o arquivo de banco de dados vazio, este é o padrão para o HSQLDB. Mas deve-se tomar cuidado pois se o caminho for informado erroneamente, não dará erro, pois um novo banco será criado no caminho errado. Para evitar isso, é interessante adicionar o argumento `;ifexists=true` na conexão após o banco já existir, para evitar esse tipo de problema.

```
Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(
     "jdbc:hsqldb:file:/opt/db/testdb;ifexists=true", "SA", "");
```

Dessa forma, caso o caminho seja alterado e o banco não existir naquele caminho, ele irá disparar uma exceção.

As formas apresentadas são para conexão de banco [**standalone**](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/running-chapt.html#rgc_inprocess), para o modo server [**há outras formas**](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/running-chapt.html#rgc_server_modes):

- conexão local do banco na mesma maquina usando o protocolo `hsql`:

  ```
  Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(
       "jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/xdb", "SA", "");
  ```
- usando o protocolo HTTP:

  ```
  Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(
       "jdbc:hsqldb:http://localhost/xdb", "SA", "");
  ```

Onde `xdb` é o nome do banco de dados em que será conectado.

> Obs.: "SA" é o usuário padrão do HSQLDB sem senha, por isso os códigos acima foram apresentados com ele. Se quiser criar seu próprio usuário e senha, estes devem ser informados na criação do banco.